# android path to my file

Tags: android, file, path

I'm using a very complex method (not written by me) in my android app, which takes a String parameter "path" and then opens and parses the file from that path.
The problem is this: When i set the path to a file on my sdcard (like this: **Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/myfile.txt"** ) it works fine.
But i don't want my file to be available for the user so i tried to set the path to the assets folder in my project where i copied the file, and using this path it won't work.The path I used for the file in my assets folder wast this: **file:///android_asset/myfile.txt** 
So why the first path works fine and the second does nothing?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have access (and rights) to edit the code of the "very complex method" that you are using?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [AssetManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html) to access the files in assets folder.

Comment: To help clarify, this is because the assets folder in your app project is park of the .apk archive, and is not a separate folder on the device or emulator when the app is installed, so you can't access it using normal file access functions.

Answer (score 0):

So what i did was this: i wrote a method that copies the file from the assets to the data directory of my app and then sending this path to the "very complex method".
Now it works fine.
Code sample (maybe it will help others in the future):

///opening the file from the assets folder

InputStream in = getAssets().open("myfile.txt");

///creating the output and the location to it

///you can set any path you like

(new File("data/data/myAppPackageName/databases/")).mkdirs();

OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("data/data/myAppPackageName/databases/myfile.txt");

///copy method from "in" to "out"

Path sent as parameter to the "very complex method":
"data/data/myAppPackageName/databases/myfile.txt"